# Ruby Regular expression to extract string between first ( and last )

Tags: ruby, regex

I have a string:

```
"whatever( here i com  ( asdfasDF ( ) ) ) go home"
```

I want to extract everything between the first `"("` and last `")"` which is:

```
" here i com  ( asdfasDF ( ) ) "
```

What is a good regular expression to extract that?

---

Update:

If my string contains newline chars the following works:

```
/\((([.|\s|\S])*)\)/
```

Comment: have you tried running through some basic regex tutorials?

Comment: http://rubular.com/ is great for testing out regexes.

Comment: "Your string"? Whose string? Didn't you write "Lets say **I** have a string"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A greedy expression with a capture, e.g.:

```
/\((.*)\)/
```

Comment: this breaks when I have new line characters in my string

Answer (score 3):

```
"whatever( here i com  ( asdfasDF ( ) ) ) go home"[/\((.*)\)/m, 1]
```

or

```
"whatever( here i com  ( asdfasDF ( ) ) ) go home"[/(?<=\().*(?=\))/m]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
str = "whatever( here i com ( asdfasDF ( ) ) ) go home"
p str[str.index("(")+1..str.rindex(")")-1]
```

Comment: could you do `str[str.index("(")+1...str.rindex(")")-1]`?

Comment: @JanDvorak Excellent post tips :) done according to you... like it :)

Comment: Actually, I mixed up `...` (right-exclusive) and `..` (inclusive). I meant the latter. I've just tested (I hoped you would)